# Idris compilation from source failed

Tags: ghc, cabal, idris, cabal-install

I'm trying to build latest dev version 1.3.2 of Idris from source code (`bbd0f286c2e76ae157b5130303d29622d31de309`) with these commands

```
$ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
$ cabal v1-sandbox init
$ cabal update
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
```

But I'm getting the following error

> idris: No trivial solution

```
Building libraries...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C prelude build
../../dist/dist-sandbox-b79b3f63/build/idris/idris --build prelude.ipkg
Type checking ./Builtins.idr
Type checking ./Prelude/Uninhabited.idr
Type checking ./Prelude/Algebra.idr
Type checking ./Prelude/Bool.idr
Type checking ./Prelude/Basics.idr
Type checking ./Prelude/Interfaces.idr
idris: No trivial solution
make[2]: *** [build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [build] Error 2
cabal: Leaving directory '.'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
idris-1.3.2-2S4MqcVuueB5TIZWBFxuhX failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 2
```

Is it something wrong with a code for language itself or something incorrect with the build process I'm following? How to properly debug this issue and in which place should I look first?

```
➜ cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.0.0.0
compiled using version 3.0.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

`ghcup 0.0.8` and `ghci version 8.6.5`, `GNU Make 3.81` MacOS Catalina.

Comment: given your more recent question, did you resolve this?

Comment: @JoelB no, I did installation with a help of homebrew, build from source code still gives me an error